# Session handling in Google oauth

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-authentication

I'm using Google's javascript auth library for authenticating users to my webapp where I check the token's expiry for validity.
Currently I'm using the client-side only oauth flow.

Few questions:

1. Does Google auth handle token refresh by itself or do I have to do so manually?
2. If it does handle token refresh by itself - is there a hook method I can use to detect when the access token has changed?
3. If it doesn't - what alternatives am I facing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisiting this question:

1. After a lot of trial and error I've come to the conclusion that Google's javascript auth lib does handle the refreshing of tokens on its own.
2. No there is no such hook available.
3. N/A.